# Is there a solution for translating Spanish to English and vice versa in emails? Using ExactTarget?

Tags: email, exacttarget, machine-translation

Is there a way using ExactTarget that I can send out a spanish email but provide a english option without generating 2 different emails? I thought about table driven but is there a technology out there that can be called from an EMAIL Communication that will translate on the spot to an English version?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can utilize the [Content Syndication](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/content_syndication/) functionality in the platform to pull in content from any publicly available web service (using the [httpget()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/#HTTPGet) [AMPScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/) function).  I would not recommend it for translating content.

It's much more accurate to capture the subscribers preferred language and serve up the email in their own language.  There are numerous ways to do this in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ET).  It can also be done in a single email using AMPScript and/or [SSJS](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/server_side_javascript/).

Also, there is a lot more SFMC dicussion going on over in [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud).